# How are the envfit results created for factor variables?

Tags: r, pca, vegan, rda

I was trying to figure out how envfit results were generated and came across this post which was super helpful: [How are envfit results created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60953996/how-are-envfit-results-created)

However, I am still confused as to how this would be transposed for factor variables as a linear regression would not make sense as I understand that the environmental factors are treated as dependent variables? I do understand that the coefficients on the ordination axes represent the average of all sites that are part of one category, but where does the R2 comes from?

As logistic and multinomial regression do not provide standard R2, I assume this is not what is done for factors.

Also, if linear regression is the underlying modelling method in envfit, what is the advantage of performing it with permutation tests in opposition to the unique coefficient/p-value that would be obtained by using least squares methods?

I am trying to understand a bit better the function as I am planning to use it in a publication and would prefer to make sure I understand well what I am presenting.

Comment: Principal compoents analysis has some similarities to linear regression but the features being minimized are not the squared distances from a line or hyper plane. Rather there is an effort to summarize within group orientations within a reduced “virtual” space. This is the wrong place to augment your knowledge about the extent of linear methods. Despite the fact that you are using R this is fundamentally a statistics question. This might be an interesting test case for chatGPT 4.0. My experience with 3.5 has been poor, but maybe 4.0 is better? It’s got to learn stats some time. :-)

Comment: This is not about the pca (this part is clear to me), but a specific function called envfit in the package vegan that performs tests on various ordinations. The previous person who asked a related question (referred in my post) about that method did so here, so I assumed it would be the right place. The distinction between stackoverflow and crossvalidated is still confusing to me, everytime I posted in the latter regarding R questions, I was also told it is not the right place.

Comment: Without a specific case it’s difficult to determine where the problem lies. The explanations I have seen say there is an attempt to apply something like PCA in the context of ordination. Since PCA  is not linear regression but does use mathematical methods similar to linear regression it seems more a methods question. If you don’t have an example to talk about and apply code to then SO is the wrong place.

Comment: There is no problem, I am just trying to understand how the results of the envfit function are generated for variables of type factor. As I said I posted here due to a similar question posted here for a different class of variables that got answered very clearly and thoroughly (and referred in the post). I am curious as where would be the right place otherwise?

Comment: The R2 values are generated in the same way as they are generated in linear models with factor variables. Look there. Total variance is for one general mean, residual variance is for class means (w.r.t. factor levels), and their difference is "explained variance" and  1 – residual/total is R2. This is told in the documentation of the function: try help(envfit).

Comment: The coders way is to look at the function code. Best approach for that process is to use the package version of the source since is more likely to have comments.